# Connecting to my company mail server

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, pop3

I want my fellow workers in my company, able to connect to work mail from home, 
we are able to retrieve the mails through outlook express but not thunderbird.
So our employees using thunderbird can't retrieve these emails.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could you outlook.com's web based interface to connect to POP3 accounts, similar to what you do in outlook express.

Similarly you could add your email as additional account in gmail too.